# Standard input C++

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdin

I need to take standard input to my .exe file from in.txt and push output to out.txt like:

`$ a.exe < in.txt > out.txt`

I know that with `>` you can forward output from `std::cout` to a file, but I don't know how to get input from a file like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` is putting the data on the standard input stream. So `std::cin` is the way to go.